# direct sql query or collection fast for fetch large data collection in magento?

Tags: magento-1.9, model, custom, query, optimization

I need a suggestion in magento.

I have created custom model collection.it has around `50,000` rows in `testimonial_record`. I want to fetch simply all data.

Which following query is best to fetch fast data ?

**Technique 1:**

```
$resource = Mage::getSingleton('core/resource');

        $readConnection = $resource->getConnection('core_read');

$query = 'SELECT * FROM ' . $resource->getTableName('testimonial_record');        

        $results = $readConnection->fetchAll($query);
```

**Technique 2:**

```
$collection = Mage::getModel('testimonial/record')->getCollection();
```

**Which one above technique is best to fetch fast bulk data ?**
OR any other query to fetch fast data from custom table ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Whenever you deal with database queries you should always use collections or resource model.

**It's best practice to avoid writing direct SQL queries like technique #1 elsewhere than collection / resource model.**

In terms of performance I reckon the collection do a little bit more than a simple `fetchAll` but best bet is to test. See the results between the two techniques in terms of speed and memory used. Also **using collections has the big benefit of providing you direct Magento objects** to deal with which is more convenient.

Also if you want to speed up the process I suggest you have a look at the walk iterator which will consume way less memory than looping through a collection: http://inchoo.net/magento/working-with-large-magento-collections/

Comment: I have test data for both query.In test result direct sql query is faster than collection so why we use collection in magento ?

Comment: @test to be able to access the object functionalities directly without loading them after the direct SQL queries I suggest you have a look here it'll give you a good explanation on how it works and why we use it: http://alanstorm.com/magento_collections